# Convert dates to season year

Tags: r, date, range

How can I change a specific range of dates to the games' season? For illustration: my dataframe d$Date has dates between '08/08/15' and '05/05/16', however I want to change all those dates to the specific season '2015/16'. Furthermore the dates between '08/08/14' and '05/05/15' should be '2014/15' What line of code could accomplish this?

Comment: Take a look at `?cut.Date` - it is possible to cut up a series of dates by intervals like you would any other numeric vector.

Comment: I have tried gsub('[0-9]/08/16', '2015/16', d$Date); this gives "02015/16" "02015/16" "02015/16" "02015/16" "02015/16" "02015/16" "02015/16" "02015/16" "02015/16"
  [10] "12015/16" "12015/16" "12015/16" "12015/16" "12015/16" "12015/16" "12015/16" "12015/16" "12015/16"

Comment: My definition for seasons is the period of time in which participants of a game compete with each other for a prize. For example each year soccer clubs compete in the premier league and start over the next season. I wish to classify the games played to a specific season.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lubridate` package is your friend:

```
library(lubridate)
date <- c("08/08/15", "08/09/16")

# extract year information 
year <- year(mdy(date))
# paste season 
season <- paste0(year, "/", year + 1)
season
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thanks, that package is really intuitive! I did have to change 'mdy' to 'dmy' to avoid parsing errors, but that is a detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... and let me know if it help?

```
    DF <- data.frame(matchDate = as.POSIXct(as.Date(sample(1000,100,replace=TRUE), origin="2000-01-01")))

years <- 1999:2016
DF$season <- cut(DF$matchDate, 
                 breaks=as.POSIXct(paste(years,"-01-01",sep="")),
                 labels=paste(years[-length(years)],years[-length(years)]+1,sep="/"))
```